# Cannot search again after initial search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

When i search initially, onClick of search filters and outputs results and console.log shows me an array of objects, but when i clear the input box and want to search something new the html page still contains the previous search results and when I condole.log, the new searched item is an empty array.

```
this.state = { 
   search: data, 
   query: "", 
   resultFound: false
   }

onInput = (event) => {
          this.setState({ query : event.target.value })
         }

multiFilter = (array, filters) => {
          const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters)
// filters all elements passing the criteria
          return array.filter(item => {
// dynamically validate all filter criteria
          return filterKeys.every(key => !filters[key].indexOf(item[key]))
        })
        }

onSearch = () => {
         const { query, search } = this.state
             if (query.length > 0) {
             console.log("Query string is ", query)
         const filterThis = {
             "topname" : (query)
         }
         const filtered = this.multiFilter(search, filterThis)
             this.setState({ search: filtered,
                             resultFound: true }) } 
         }  

return (
    <div> 
    <input type="text" value={this.state.query} onChange={this.onInput} />
    <button onClick={() => this.onSearch()}> Search </button> 
    </div> )
```

[image: A]
[image: B]

I currently have to reload the page for every search and don't want this. Why this happen? Pls help. I have seen similar questions asked but wasn't able to apply it to my circumstance.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Sure, but will take some time to add, never used either and will have to learn how they work

Answer (score 0):

React does shallow compare of each state that you provide as props and if it is new variable then triggers another render. Your `this.multiFilter` might not be immutable and mutating same object. If this is the case try this :

```
const filtered = [ ...this.multiFilter(search, filterThis) ];
```

But better fix your function and make it immutable.

Comment: I added my multiFilter function above, is it what you were saying? it was mutating the same object?

Comment: No, it creates new array, not mutating. It should have worked if it would be the case. Where do you render search? Also your console.log's are intended results?

Comment: What your code did also turned my array of objects into objects, and i am now not able to map or reduce since it would have to be an array for me to do those functions. i believe..My console.log for 800 should look like the G90 console.log, but has an empty array instead

Comment: Upps.. yes it supposed to be array. I've updated the answer.